# Centering a box with Css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, centering

I can't seem to put this bar in the center of the page

My code

```css
#menu-header {
  background-color: #009376;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div><br></br>
  <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="navbar-header">
        <br/>
        <div>
          <div id="menu-header" className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
            <h4>&emsp;Cocktails</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated , thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you better use -

```css
.menu-header-parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#menu-header {
  background-color: #009376;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  width: 900px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div><br></br>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <br/>
        <div class="menu-header-parent">
          <div id="menu-header" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
            <h4>&emsp;Cocktails</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Here as [**referral link**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for you to understand `display: flex`. I hope this helps you if there is anything else feel free to ask.

Comment: @Ibo If it was the answer you are looking for plz do mark it as answer.

Comment: unfortunately it wasn't my friend , but thank you for taking your time to help

Comment: @Ibo it will work.. I am using it now and then.. always.. can you give me a live version of your Q??

Comment: What do you mean by Q?

Comment: @Ibo Q = Question, what I meant was a live sample of your issue.!

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/8fntWC1.png

Comment: `.navbar-header{
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 7em;
  padding-top: 3em;
}
#menu-header{
  background-color:#009376;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  height: -30px;
  width: 900px;
  color:white;
}
#menu-items{
  background-color:#009376;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  height: -30px;
  width: 900px;
  color:white;
  opacity: 0.7;

}`

Comment: I dont know how to ident it properly sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154680/discussion-between-weber-and-ibo).

Comment: @Ibo please see my answers out in an expanded view **the green bar** is now **`centred`**. So what is exactly you want.?

Comment: Thanks , i'm sorry for taking so much of your time but i managed to solve the issue through another way

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the div vertically on the screen, either you can use positioning or you can use margin-top.

unit vh is used to get the vertical screen height.

Eg:

```
height: 100vh // gets the full height of the screen
```

**Margin-top Method**

```
#menu-header{
 background-color:#009376;
 padding-top:3px;
 padding-right:3px;
 padding-bottom:2px;
 padding-left:3px;
 width: 900px;
 display: flex;
 align-self: center;
 margin-top: calc( 50vh - 33px );
}
```

But in this method you are more likely to end up with wasting the top space.

**Positioning**

```
#menu-header{
 background-color:#009376;
 padding-top:3px;
 padding-right:3px;
 padding-bottom:2px;
 padding-left:3px;
 width: 900px;
 display: flex;
 align-self: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: calc( 50vh - 33px );
}
```

Here the div is positioned absolute and given a top value.

https://jsfiddle.net/sinthu225/hp2ubymL/

In Both solution Im calculating the top / margin top value by getting the half of actual screen height and deducting the half of the div height

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: No it didnt unfortunately , thank you though

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: I wanted to center the bar i had created , unfortunately the snippet tool doesnt produce what i have here , i fixed the problem with using other Css tools such as padding

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code to bring it to the middle, only thing you need to do is, you should provide height and width of the div.

```
#navbar-header {
    position: relative;
}
#menu-header{
  background-color:#009376;
  padding-top:3px;
  padding-right:3px;
  padding-bottom:2px;
  padding-left:3px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```